# Long timeline (with chronology-package or otherwise) showing vertical dashes that indicate year

Tags: tikz-pgf, timeline, chronology

I need to include in a paper a longer timeline, and I almost get the desired result with the chronology-package, but the longer timeline doesn't show any vertical dashes that indicate the year (such as -250, 0, 250...), which looks poor. I tried to rebuild a similar timeline with tikz, but apparently aren't skilled enough to get a better result. I guess, the chronology-package itself hasn't a solution for that problem, but perhaps someone has an idea how to work around that or to recreate such a timeline in some way? Help would be greatly appreciates, and here is a MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{chronology}


\begin{document}

    \begin{chronology}[250]{-500}{1675}{\textwidth}[100ex]
        \eventpoint{-399}{Person 1 (\dag -399)}[black][25][25]
        \eventpoint{-322}{Person 2 (\dag -348) and Person 3 (\dag -322)}[black][25][25]
        \eventpoint{-232}{Person 4 (\dag -261) and Person 5 (\dag -232)}[black][25][25]
        \eventpoint{-43}{Person 6 (\dag -43)}[black][25][25]
        \eventpoint{65}{Person 7 (\dag 65)}[black][25][25]
        \eventpoint{950}{Person 8 (\dag 950)}[black][25][25]
        \eventpoint{1037}{Person 9 (\dag 1037)}[black][25][25]
        \eventpoint{1198}{Person 10 (\dag 1198)}[black][25][25]
        \eventpoint{1274}{Person 11 (\dag 1274) and Person 12 (\dag 1280)}[black][25][25]
    \end{chronology}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [`chronos`](https://codeberg.org/cfr/chronos) version. It currently depends on an internal command, but I will have to provide a public version for this and maybe something to make rotation easier, if I can come up with an idea which works.

[image: chronos version with year markers]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,american,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{chronos}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{chronos}
  [
    no colour rotation,
    colour scheme=default,
    date format={!q!Y},
    year format={!q!Y},
    frame=false,
    every text tags+={font=\normalfont\footnotesize},
    event/tag+={rotate around={45:([yshift=3pt]\csname chronos@digwyddiad@tikzname\endcsname)},tag anchor=west},
    every event above,
    text tag yshift'=3pt,
    timeline={%
      minor years=false,
      timeline mark eras=false,
      year zero,
      year at era switch,
      timeline era margin'=0pt,
      step major years=250,
      timeline years=below,
      timeline font=\normalfont\footnotesize,
      timeline line+={shorten >=5pt,shorten <=\timelineht,{Bar[width=3pt]}-{Latex[length=5pt]}},
      timeline arrow,
      dates={-500}:1675,
      width'=.9\textwidth,
    },
  ]
  \chronosevent{%
    date={-399},
    text content={Person 1 (\dag -399)},
    name=p1,
  }
  \chronosevent{%
    date={-322},
    text content={Person 2 (\dag -348) and Person 3 (\dag -322)},
    name=p23,
  }
  \chronosevent{%
    date={-232},
    text content={Person 4 (\dag -261) and Person 5 (\dag -232)},
    name=p45,
  }
  \chronosevent{%
    date={-43},
    text content={Person 6 (\dag -43)},
    name=p6,
  }
  \chronosevent{%
    date={65},
    text content={Person 7 (\dag 65)},
    name=p7,
  }
  \chronosevent{%
    date={950},
    text content={Person 8 (\dag 950)},
    name=p8,
  }
  \chronosevent{%
    date={1037},
    text content={Person 9 (\dag 1037)},
    name=p9,
  }
  \chronosevent{%
    date={1198},
    text content={Person 10 (\dag 1198)},
    name=p10,
  }
  \chronosevent{%
    date={1274},
    text content={Person 11 (\dag 1274) and Person 12 (\dag 1280)},
    name=p1112,
  }
\end{chronos}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much - that looks exactly like what I needed! However, somehow I cannot find/load the package via Miktex and therefore couldn't test whether it works... Perhaps I don't have the required LATEX 2ε-format? I don't know

Comment: @Horstfuchs It is not on CTAN (yet). I put the link in the post: https://codeberg.org/cfr/chronos. You need at least the three `*.sty` files. The PDF has documentation.